# jQuery select all with the same class with simple code?

Tags: jquery, class, toggle, selector

I want to make a div, or to be more precise, an "aside" element which has an id or class to appear when another element that has the same class is clicked... I know that there is the standard class selector but I want there to be more than one "aside" element with different id's or classes and I want that one to be opened that has the same class or id as the clicked element...

So, I don't want to write the this code for every single div:

```
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('nav ul li#someid').click(function () {
      $('aside#someid').toggleClass('opened');
      });
    });
```

I want code like this. Is there a way to change the someid from the example to something that detects what id the clicked element has and use it as the "aside" selector?

Comment: Yes, use a class on the li and then within the click event get the id using `this.id`. Keep in mind, ID's must be unique, the aside can't have the same id as the li.

Comment: Show us your actual HTML if you want the best answers.

Comment: Note that `id` selectors are **meant to be unique** for the whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you may want to know that you can use `this` to access the object that was clicked on.  That means you can get `this.id` or `this.className` to get the id or class of the object that was clicked on.  Now, exactly what you do with that info depends upon how your HTML is structured so we'd need to see that to provide more specifics.

You cannot have multiple objects in the same page with the same ID.  You simply cannot do that  (selectors will not work properly when you do that) so your desired scheme will not work.  You could use classes instead and toggle the other item with the same class.  This would work for one particular `li`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav ul li.foo').click(function () {
        $('aside.foo').toggleClass('opened');
    });
 });
```

Or, depending upon your HTML (if you only have one class on the li tag), you could do a more general version like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav ul li').click(function () {
        $('aside.' + this.className).toggleClass('opened');
    });
});
```

If you show us your actual HTML, we could provide the best options.

Comment: this will fail if the clicked `li` has more than one class

Comment: @ZoltanToth - yes, I've mentioned that in my answer.  It's impossible to suggest more specifics when the OP hasn't disclosed their exact HTML.

Comment: it worked... Thank you very much... NOW the new problem is... I want all the other aside-s to close when I open another one

Comment: @user1902011 - just add `$("aside").removeClass("opened");` to remove that class from all of them before you open the desired one.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using:

```
this.id
```

**this** points to element that caught the event.

Comment: But, you can't have another element with that same id so you'll have to provide much more of a solution for this to be useful.

Comment: this.id answers the question: "Is there a way to change the someid form the example to something that detects what id the clicked element has"  I am not sure what you were asking.

Comment: "...and uses it for the aside selector" - read to the very end :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [jQuery starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)?

jQuery('[attribute^="value"]')

```
$('aside[id^="foo_"]').toggleClass('opened');
```

This will call toggleClass for all `aside` tags whose `id` attribute starts with `foo_`

As mentioned by others, you cannot have more than 1 of the same id tag, but you can start them all with `foo_` and target them using the starts with selector.... `foo_1`   `foo_2`   `foo_3` etc...

Answer (score -2):

Try like

```
  $(function(){
      $('nav ul li.someClass').click(function () {
      $('aside#aside_' + $(this).attr('id')).toggleClass('opened');
      });
    });
```

Comment: This suggests that the li and aside have the same id, which is invalid, fyi